# Cannot access SQS queue message through Lambda function - Serverless framework

Tags: node.js, lambda, serverless-framework

I have a lambda function which is suppose to read message from a SQS queue and process. When I deployed everything to AWS and try to call the lambda function getting "errorMessage":"Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied."

However, Lambda function can read the messages when it is run locally through Serverless Offline plugin. I have given proper permission as below. And my project is based on Serverless framework using node.js.
Here is the permission block,

`- Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - sqs:*
      Resource:
        - Fn::GetAtt:
          - NotificationQueue
          - Arn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem that was due to improper indentation of `iamRoleStatements` statement. Due to that Serverless has not updated policy under lambda execution role.